# Characters converted in an UTF-8 encoded POST

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a problem that in my production server all text in the post requests that contains non standard ascii characters are corrupted while the encoding is utf-8. On my development server the text is displayed fine.

```
print(mb_detect_encoding($_POST["text"]));
print($_POST["text"]);
```

Output is:
`utf-8`
`Ã?Ã?Ã? Ã?Ã?Ã? Ã?Ã?Ã?`

while input is `ÅÅÅ ÄÄÄ ÖÖÖ`

I use `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the head and `accept-charset="UTF-8"` in the form.

`<form id="announcement_form" method="post" action="php/announcment_bar.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Are you sure the original html page has been saved as utf8 ?

Comment: You may find [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/2341603) useful.

Answer (score 0):

From the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279) given to me by [Obsidian Age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822435/characters-converted-in-an-utf-8-encoded-post/42822566#comment72756532_42822435) the problem was that in the `php.ini` the [default_charset.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) Since 5.6+ the default value of `default_charset` is set to `UTF-8`. That is the reason why it worked on my development server. However since out production server was older and installed before 5.6 it used the old default value which is none/commented out.